# How to split a string around numbers?

Tags: python, regex, string

For example, take the input string `Street42/53`. I want to split it around runs of digits, so I get `['Street', '42, '/', '53']`. I tried a regex but the problem is that expressions like `(?<=\d)(?!=\d)` have no actual character to match. So I tried to replace the matches with an uncommon character and split at it.

```
import re
delimiter = re.compile(r'(?<=\d)(?!=\d)')
re.sub('Street42/53', '\f').split('\f')
```

However, this just return a list of two empty strings. How can I split around numbers in Python? To clarify, a split should occur whenever a digit is next to a non-digit, but inside runs of either just digits or just non-digits.

Comment: so what happens with `'Street442/53'`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply:

```
re.split(r'(\d+)', your_string)
```

---

```
>>> test = 'street43/23hello243world'
>>> re.split(r'(\d+)', test)
['street', '43', '/', '23', 'hello', '243', 'world']
```

Comment: You can use `[i for i in re.split(r'(\d+)', test) if i]` to get ride of empty splits

Comment: Thanks for the easy answer. I now use `filter(None, re.split(r'(\d+)', test))` for it. In my case there were some empty strings as well as None values included.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex).

```
x = "Street42/53"
print regex.split(r"(?<=\d)(?=\D)|(?<=\D)(?=\d)", x, flags=regex.VERSION1)
```

python `re` module does not support splitting on `0 width assertions` but `regex` module does.

Answer (score 0):

Since Python's `re.split` doesn't split on zero length matches here is a workaround while using zero length lookarounds:

```
import re

re.sub(r'(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)', '\0', 'Street42/53').split('\0');
//=> ['Street', '42', '/', '53']
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dW2mL5/2)